# Trying to link an image but it keeps linking all the other images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I am trying to link an image in my footer but whenever I link the one image, the link spreads to the rest of the widgets in the footer.

How do I stop this?

[My site](http://nzbound.kiwi.nz/website)

Here is the code I used to make the image linkable...

```
<a href="http://www.pastorsdigitalbooks.com"
target="_blank"><img src="http://nzbound.kiwi.nz/website/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/logo-500x500.png";width="165"; height="165";</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to make the link? It's best if you post code, rather than link to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Please post what you are adding in the footer so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: You've added the link **five** times and are placing everything from the correct image `logo-500x500.png` to javascript inside them. I'm guessing you forgot to close an `<a>` tag or accidentally added the link in more than once. Please post the code you used to add the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the `link` on the whole **Footer div** so obviously it will show on the whole area of the footer.
**Your Code:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.pastorsdigitalbooks.com">
<div id="footer-widget2"> //..... and so on
```

**Your code Should be:**

```
<div id="footer-widget2">
<div class="textwidget">
<p align="center">
<a href="">Sent from: Bible Baptist Church</a> // ... adn so on
```

NOTE: You are applying the link on your whole footer widget thats why it is overlapping on the whole div.try to format your code.

Comment: So how do I make the image linkable without applying it to the whole footer?

Comment: By doing this : `<a href="/"> <img src="your_image_path" /> </a>`